# "Tuple index out of range" when changing number of cycles

Tags: python, tuples, indexoutofrangeexception

I got the following question for you.
In the following program, a "airplane" is send from a starting airport to various airports transporting 10 people (variable : passenger_in_flight) at a time. The demand to travel from e.g. Berlin(BE) to Munich (MU)  is 54 persons. Since it has the highest demand of all destination, the airplane will fly to Munich, and from there fly to Düsseldorf(DÜ), because this route has the highest demand of all destinations from Munich as well. And so on. In the end, the airplane shall have transported everyone to his favorite destination

**The program is running, only problem I got is, that if you make it for more than 85 cycles the following error message occurs:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-46-54a5efde663e>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Ben/unbenannt4.py', wdir='C:/Users/Ben')

  File "C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Ben/unbenannt4.py", line 90, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/Ben/unbenannt4.py", line 39, in main
    vehicleA.output()

  File "C:/Users/Ben/unbenannt4.py", line 61, in output
    self.point_in_time = self.point_in_time + i[3]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

So this expression:

```
self.point_in_time = self.point_in_time + i[3]
```

causes the problem to occur. If I change the starting base ("depot"), the number of cycles executable changes. What is the cause? I already rounded self.point_in_time, because  I thought maybe that causes the problem

Sorry for the long message.
Regards, Ben

```
data = {}
data["airports"] = ["BE", "BR", "DR", "DÜ", "HAM", "MU"]
data["distance_matrix"] = [
#      BE    BR   DR   DÜ  HAM   MU
#     [0]   [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]  [5]   
    [   0, 315, 165, 477, 255, 200],#  [0]BE
    [ 315,   0, 404, 248,  95, 582],#  [1]BR
    [ 165, 404,   0, 485, 376, 359],#  [2]DR
    [ 477, 248, 485,   0, 338, 486],#  [3]Dü
    [ 255,  95, 376, 338,   0, 612],#  [4]HAM
    [ 504, 582, 359, 486, 612,   0] #  [5]MU
    ]
data["travel_demand"] = [
#   BE   BR  DR  DÜ  HAM  MU
  # [0]  [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]     
   [ 0, 100, 20, 35, 70, 20],#  [0]BE
   [35,   0, 40, 48, 95, 82],#  [1]BR
   [15,   4,  0, 45, 24, 59],#  [2]DR
   [ 47, 70, 12,  0, 33, 86],#  [3]Dü
   [ 25,  9, 36, 38,  0, 12],#  [4]HAM
   [ 54, 58, 35, 87, 62,  0] #  [5]MU
   ]

data["num_vehicles"] = 4
data['vehicle_speed'] = 250 #kmh
data["depot"] = 0
data["passenger_in_flight"] = 10
data["starttime"] = 0
data["maintenance"] = []
data["store_index"] = None

store_index = 0

def main():    
    vehicleA = airplane(data["travel_demand"], data["depot"], data["passenger_in_flight"], data["distance_matrix"], data['vehicle_speed'], data["airports"], data["starttime"], data["store_index"], data["num_vehicles"])
    vehicleA.output()

    for n in range(len(data["travel_demand"])):
        print((data["travel_demand"])[n])

class airplane():


    def __init__(self, travel_demand, depot, passengers_in_flight, distance_matrix, vehicle_speed, airports, point_in_time, store_index, num_vehicles):
        self.travel_demand = travel_demand
        self.depot = depot
        self.passengers_in_flight = passengers_in_flight
        self.distance_matrix = distance_matrix
        self.vehicle_speed = vehicle_speed
        self.airports = airports
        self.point_in_time = point_in_time
        self.store_index = store_index
        self.num_vehicles = num_vehicles

    def output(self):
        for n in range(0, 87):
            i = airplane.max_in_row(self)
            self.point_in_time = self.point_in_time + i[3]
            self.point_in_time = round(self.point_in_time, 4)
            print((i[0]),  " --> " ,(i[1])," ; ", i[2]," ; ", i[3]," ; ", self.point_in_time)    

    def max_in_row(self):    
        b = self.travel_demand                                  # ["travel_demand"] # liste der einzelnen Flughäfen, wieviele dahin wollen
        level = []                                  # von welcher spalte starten wir   
        for i in range(len(b)):

            if self.point_in_time == 0:
                store_indexold = self.depot
            else:
                store_indexold = self.store_index        # die reihe wird durchgegangen
            level.append(b[i][store_indexold])         # der liste level werden die werte der reihe hinzugefügt, die spalte bleibt gleich                 

        self.store_index = level.index(max(level))       # der index des maxwertes wird übergeben (zeile wird bestimmt, spalte ist gegeben)
                  # 
        if b[i][store_index] < 10:
           return (store_index, b[i][store_index])
        else:
           y = max(level) - self.passengers_in_flight                   #der maxwert selbst wird übergeben
        self.travel_demand[self.store_index][store_indexold] = y
        traveltime = int(self.distance_matrix[self.store_index][store_indexold])/int(self.vehicle_speed)
        airport_last = self.airports[store_indexold]
        airport_next = self.airports[self.store_index]
        return(airport_last, airport_next, y, traveltime)        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your code, you have an additional return in the max_in_row method that returns a tuple of length 2. You th en try to access index 3,that's causing out of range.

Comment: Thank you =D. I am not stupid, but sometimes I got bad luck thinking and I think this is one of these cases =D.